# Is it possible to have multiple xmlRootElements?

Tags: java, jaxb, resteasy

I need to have a VO which will represent the following XML

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
  <ORDER_NUM>5101330188</ORDER_NUM>
  <LINE_NUM_SEQ>55</LINE_NUM_SEQ>
  <PROD_NUM_REQ>9BX134-505</PROD_NUM_REQ>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

How can I define 2 xmlRootElements representing Rowset and Row? My VO is something like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ROWSET")
public class TestVo {

    String ORDER_NUM;
    String LINE_NUM_SEQ;
    String PROD_NUM_REQ;

    @XmlElement
    public String getLINE_NUM_SEQ() {
        return LINE_NUM_SEQ;
    }

    public void setLINE_NUM_SEQ(String lINE_NUM_SEQ) {
        LINE_NUM_SEQ = lINE_NUM_SEQ;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getORDER_NUM() {
        return ORDER_NUM;
    }

    public void setORDER_NUM(String oRDER_NUM) {
        ORDER_NUM = oRDER_NUM;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getPROD_NUM_REQ() {
        return PROD_NUM_REQ;
    }

    public void setPROD_NUM_REQ(String pROD_NUM_REQ) {
        PROD_NUM_REQ = pROD_NUM_REQ;
    }

}
```

I cannot have 2 XMLROOTELEMENTS but I need to define `<ROWSET>` & `<ROW>`.

Comment: It seems to me, from your example, that only `<ROWSET>` is a root element, while `<ROW>` is a child. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - what is a VO?

Comment: @DaveRlz: Likely "Value Object". It's probably part of de-/serializing a POJO to/from XML.

Comment: @Henrick - exactly... how to define child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution is to change `@XmlRootElement(name = "ROWSET")` to `@XmlRootElement(name = "ROW")` and to invent an object like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ROWSET")
public class Rowset{

    private List<TestVo> vos;
    [...]
}
```

Because XML can not have more than one root.

Comment: Bro one quickone.. right now.. my output is like
<collection>
 <ROWSET>
<BILL_TO_NUM>02184000</BILL_TO_NUM>
<CUST_REF_NUM>TESTINGNSNQTY</CUST_REF_NUM>
<HEADER_STATUS>O</HEADER_STATUS>
<LINE_NUM_SEQ>55</LINE_NUM_SEQ>
<ORDER_NUM>5101330188</ORDER_NUM>
<PACKAGE_ID>STH006N5</PACKAGE_ID>
<PROD_NUM_REQ>9BX134-505</PROD_NUM_REQ>
<QIS_RTN_TYPE>C</QIS_RTN_TYPE>
<RTN_REASON>F</RTN_REASON>
<SHIP_TO_NUM>08882002</SHIP_TO_NUM>
 </ROWSET>
 </collection>
How can I change the name of Collection to some custom label? Collection is automatically generated label. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An XML file can not have more than one root element as that would violate the W3C standards. A root element is a container that packages the individual elements of the XML document.
For more details please follow [w3c standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)

Comment: Downvoting because suggesting that someone read a 40+ page document as a fix to their problem is the pinnacle of unhelpfulness.

Comment: An XML file cannot have more than one root element. An XML schema however can define more than one element under the schema root. This allows you to validate multiple XML files or extracts for which the root element is defined as a top-level element in the schema. JAXB might need @XmlRootElement because it needs to know WHICH element name to marshal to. But if you have a complex type that could be marshalled to more than one element, you'll have to choose. Hence the ObjectFactory.